# Submenu not clickable on hover

Tags: css, wordpress, submenu

My submenu is not working properly. It's showing up, but if you click on the parent of the submenu, the color doesn't change. It's not even clickable, which makes me think that there's something that's blocking it. I know where the problem lies, a bit, but I don't know how I should solve it.

```
ul li ul {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:-5px;
    padding-top:2em;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

The top:-5px breaks it down. When I comment it out, the submenu's working, but it doesn't stick to the parent li. Someone else made this, and I am trying to solve it. Since I can't contact him, it's my job to fix this.

[Link to site](http://saints.mousecraft.nl/)

Try clicking on "teams", or hover over it, then you'll see what I mean...

Edit: I have made a JSFiddle, trying to tidy the things up a bit.

[It can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Qj7r5FUDDg)

Comment: attach all of your menu codes! and send a jsfiddle demo for that

Comment: Clicks involve Javascript usually...what are you using?

Comment: The first thing to do is to validate your CSS. I see that in some places, you're trying to use `//` for comment, which doesn't work in CSS. That said, the page works for me: hovering over Teams brings up a fully functional submenu.

Comment: Yes, but they client wants that users can click on "teams" too. I don't know why you would want that when you're using a submenu, but they, the client is the king. I am more a backender, I don't do much CSS, but this should be fixable for me...I thought

Comment: The link to the JSfiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `ul` is over the `anchor` element you can change it like so:

```
ul li ul {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     z-index: 999;
     top: 12px;
     padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Answer updated, combine the padding and top. I also don't believe the float was necessary.

Comment: Hey, thanks! This fixed it! I would give you a kiss if I could. Know what? *digital smooch*